# Spring test @ContextConfiguration and static context

Tags: spring, junit

I have the following piece of code for my abstract test class (I know `XmlBeanFactory` with `ClassPathResource` is deprecated, but it's unlikely to be the case of the problem).

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
public abstract class AbstractIntegrationTest {

    /** Spring context. */
    protected static final BeanFactory context = new XmlBeanFactory(new ClassPathResource(
            "com/.../AbstractIntegrationTest-context.xml"));

    ...

}
```

It loads the default test configuration XML file `AbstractIntegrationTest-context.xml` (and then I use autowiring). I also need to use Spring in static methods annotated with `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass`, so I have a separate context variable pointing to the same location. But the thing is that this is a separate context, which will have different instances of beans. So how can I merge these contexts or how can I invoke Spring's bean initialization defined by `@ContextConfiguration` from my static context?

I have in mind a possible solution by getting rid of those static members, but I'm curious, if I can do it with relatively small changes to the code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are right, your code will produce two application contexts: one will be started, cached and maintained for you by `@ContextConfiguration` annotation. The second context you create yourself. It doesn't make much sense to have both.

Unfortunately JUnit is not very well suited for integration tests - mainly because you cannot have *before class* and *after class* non-static methods. I see two choices for you:

- switch to [testng](/questions/tagged/testng) - I know it's a big step
- encode your setup/tear down logic in a Spring bean included in the context only during tests - but then it will run only once, before all tests.

There are also less elegant approaches. You can use `static` variable and inject context to it:

```
private static ApplicationContext context;

@AfterClass
public static afterClass() {
    //here context is accessible
}

@Autowired
public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    context = applicationContext;
}
```

Or you can annotate your test class with [`@DirtiesContext`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/annotation/DirtiesContext.html) and do the cleanup in some test bean:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
@DirtiesContext(classMode = AFTER_CLASS)
public abstract class AbstractIntegrationTest {

    //...

}

public class OnlyForTestsBean {

    @PreDestroy
    public void willBeCalledAfterEachTestClassDuringShutdown() {
        //..
    }

}
```

Comment: Concerning the second choice. Running once before all tests is not a big problem. The thing is, how to do the *after class* logic?

Comment: The first solutions remains the question open: "From *where* to get the application context to inject?" The second one must be working. I will try it.

Comment: @Vic: in the solution with `setApplicationContext()` setter is called by the application context loaded via `@ContextConfiguration` and assigns context to static variable. In principle should work.

Answer (score 7):

Not sure whether you chose any approach here, but I encounter the same problem and solved it another way using Spring test framework's [`TestExecutionListener`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/TestExecutionListener.html#beforeTestClass%28org.springframework.test.context.TestContext%29).

There are `beforeTestClass` and `afterTestClass`, so both equivalent to `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass` in JUnit.

The way I do it:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TestExecutionListeners(Cleanup.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/integrationtest/rest_test_app_ctx.xml" })
public abstract class AbstractIntegrationTest {
    // Start server for integration test.
}
```

You need to create a class that extends AbstractTestExecutionListener:

```
public class Cleanup extends AbstractTestExecutionListener
{

   @Override
   public void afterTestClass(TestContext testContext) throws Exception
   {
      System.out.println("cleaning up now");
      DomainService domainService=(DomainService)testContext.getApplicationContext().getBean("domainService");
      domainService.delete();

   }
}
```

By doing this, you have access to the application context and do your setup/teardown here with spring beans.

Hopefully this help anyone trying to do integration test like me using JUnit + Spring.

Comment: Thanks for another solution. As far as I remember, I did chose the Tomasz's approach.

Comment: Using the @TestExecutionListeners annotation appears to replace the use of the default listeners (so you lose dependency injection for example); any idea how to append to the default set instead?

Comment: @MatthewWise You can specify the merge mode of your listener: `@TestExecutionListeners(value = MyListener.class,
      mergeMode = TestExecutionListeners.MergeMode.MERGE_WITH_DEFAULTS)`

Comment: @OliverHernandez I must have missed that property, thanks!

Comment: Thank you thank you! thank you! Your example allowed me to solve a different-but-related problem that had me stuck for *two years*: how to keep a legacy code adapter with this static field in sync with the *many* Spring Contexts that exist during a large test-suite. See related question [Spring static context accessor and integration tests](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37548897/2964696), and my answer there.