# Spring static context accessor and integration tests

Tags: spring, spring-test

We have a spring component which sets the application context into a static field. This static field is then accessed from other parts of the application. I know `static` should not be used, but sometimes it is necessary to access spring context from non-spring-managed beans. E.g. the field looks like this:

```
public class ApplicationContextProvider implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static ApplicationContext context;

    public ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        return context;
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext ctx) {
        context = ctx;
    }
}
```

(taken for http://www.dcalabresi.com/blog/java/spring-context-static-class/)

The problem is that when using JUnit (or Spock) framework in integration tests, a new spring context is created for tests that have annotations like `@TestPropertySource` or `@ContextConfiguration`, in that case the contexts are cached for other tests with the same configuration (context caching in spring test framework).

However, the static field is only updated when the spring context is created. That means, when a test context is retrieved from the cache, it does not update the static field, of course, because the context was already initialized before being cached. The static field was already overwritten by the last context created from previous test runs with different configuration and so it does not see the same context as the one that starts the test.

The consequence is that part of the test runs in one spring context and from the point it accesses the static field it runs in the other context.

Does anybody have a solution to this problem? Anybody got into the same situation?

Comment: 2023, spring 5, and my $DAYJOB has *exactly* the same problem, with no solution yet in sight..

Comment: Brainwave, writing it down before going to sleep (brain, please cache this for Monday!) 1) The test context is managed by Springs `TestContextManager`, which 2) provides beforeclass/after class, with 3) current TestContext as argument! in [`TestExecutionListener`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/TestExecutionListener.html). Make a custom`AbstractTestExecutionListener` and update your `ApplicationContextProvider` static field in there! (till breaks if you run tests in parallel/multithreaded, though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**: You will need a custom `TestExecutionListener`, which is Springs' hook into the test lifecycle. It provides a `beforeTestClass`/`afterTestClass` method, *which receives the current `TestContext` as parameter*.
You can then use this test-context to update your `ApplicationContextProvider`.

### Details

I have been struggling with the exact same problem for over two years at work. The seemingly random, bizarre test failures have driven me DEEP into the `SpringJUnit4Runner`, its `DefaultApplicationContextCache`. JUnit's (intentionally pseudorandom) test ordering.
This weekend, I finally stumbled on the missing puzzle piece: `TestExecutionListener.beforeTestClass(TestContext)`.

The below example Listener-implementation double-checks if `ApplicationContextProvider`'s static field matches the test's `ApplicationContext` (from `TestContext`), and repairs it if not.
It triggered 9 times in our test-suite of several hundred test-classes (quite a few of the context-switches are handled correctly by the normal `ApplicationContextAware` behaviour.)

I'm still amazed our test-suite was working *at all* despite this.
(Then again, I've lost multiple *weeks* hunting down lost application events, only to realise the production code was, *once again*, firing them on a different EventHandler-instance than the test was listening to, ARGH)

### Using your custom Listener

You'll need to inform your tests to actually *use* the listener.
Available options:

- activate by annotation on *each and every* test class

  - `@TestExecutionListeners(value = ApplicationContextProviderSyncer.class, mergeMode = TestExecutionListeners.MergeMode.MERGE_WITH_DEFAULTS)`
  - you'll need the `MERGE_WITH_DEFAULTS`, or else the default listeners
    stop working (which breaks things like `@Autowired` and `@Value`)
  - boiler-platey, and you can forget
- Annotation on a shared base-class

  - same annotation, but on a shared base-class
  - useful if you already have a base, terribly inconvenient if you don't
- activation by default via Springs "Factories Loader" mechanism

  - define key `org.springframework.test.context.TestExecutionListener: ApplicationContextProviderSyncer.class` in `META-INF/spring.factories`
  - docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/testing/testcontext-framework/tel-config.html

### Example `TestExecutionListener` implementation

For a more detailed version, see the [worked example GitLab snippet](https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/3611200).

```java
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestContext;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestExecutionListener;


/**
 * Keeps legacy-code adapter {@link ApplicationContextProvider} in sync with <em>currently active</em> Spring test context, correctly handling caching etc.
 *
 * @author Jules Kerssemakers
 */
public class ApplicationContextProviderSyncer extends AbstractTestExecutionListener {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ApplicationContextProviderSyncer.class);

    @Override
    public void beforeTestClass(TestContext testContext) {
        ApplicationContext next = testContext.getApplicationContext();

        ApplicationContext previous = null;
        if (ApplicationContextProvider.hasContext()) {
            previous = ApplicationContextProvider.getContext();
        }

        if (!next.equals(previous)) {
            LOGGER.info("""
                    Synchronizing ApplicationContext for {}: replacing
                           {}
                      with {}""",
                    testContext.getTestClass().getSimpleName(),
                      previous, next);

            ApplicationContextProvider.setContext(next);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've faced with tha same issue.
The possible solution might be saving context before test and restoring it after.
For convinience it can be done via junit rule:

```
public class ContextRestoreRule extends ExternalResource {

    private ApplicationContext context;

    @Override
    protected void before() throws Throwable {
        context = ApplicationContextProvider.getContext();
    }

    @Override
    protected void after() {
        ApplicationContextProvider.setContext(context);
    }
}
```

And in the test (wich modifies context):

```
@ClassRule
public static ContextRestoreRule contextRestore = new ContextRestoreRule();
```

Comment: This won't work, or at least not work *reliably*, depending on the (not predictable!) order in which your tests run. If A runs before B, B is the "test which modifies". If you then add new test C, JUnit shuffles test order, so you *could* get new order, A>C>B, making *C* the "test which modifies". I ran into this multiple times at work, as we expanded our test suite.. JUnit *intentionally* doesn't specify test order, only that it is pseudo-randomly derived from the suite (so constant across runs, until you add/remove tests)